# Rename images in file based on csv in Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a folder with a couple thousand images named: `10000.jpg`, `10001.jpg`, etc.; and a `csv` file with two columns: `id` and `name`. 
The csv `id` matches the images in the folder.

I need to rename the images as per the `name` column in the csv (e.g. from `10000.jpg` to `name1.jpg`.

I've been trying the `os.rename()` inside a for loop as per below.

```
with open('train_labels.csv') as f:
    lines = csv.reader(f)
    for line in lines:
        os.rename(line[0], line[1])
```

This gives me an encoding error inside the loop.

Any idea what I'm missing in the logic?

Also tried another strategy (below), but got the error: `IndexError: list index out of range`.

```
with open('train_labels.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ' ', quotechar='|')
    for line in lines:
        os.rename(line[0], line[1])
```

Comment: that's most likely something going on within the csv file. try specifying the mode in with open as 'r'

Comment: Can you please post the actual error? So the value in the `name` column for the same line as the `id` column is what you want to rename?

Comment: here's the specific error:     f = (bs.decode(encoding, errors=errors) for bs in f)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: @pstatix, yes, just assign `name` to the image according to `id`. I think I'm pretty close.

Comment: Well in Python 3, a string is already decoded (its already UTF). Further, that line of code is not shown in your example, so please provide the problematic code in its entirety.

Comment: The second strategy worked, the csv file did not have the `.jpg` extension explicitly written (I'm just bright).
Now my problem just became another: `name` repeats itself. Will post another question.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error. When i opened CSV file in notepad, I found that there was no comma between ID and name. So please check it. otherwise you can see the solutions in [Renaming images in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296315/renaming-images-in-folder/51296626#51296626)