# Python (FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3])

Tags: python

I was having issues **printing a list of file names** from my F: drive when running Python. The script would return:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'F:\Udacity\prank.zip\prank'

whenever I tried to run the code.

I solved the issue by placing the files into my C: drive but wondered why that was so. I feel like I'm missing something important when it comes to understanding the fundamentals of hard drives and how computers access them. I've looked all around, but it seems like everyone else is in a slightly more different situation than I am, albeit they were getting the same WinError.

The following is my code before the change:

```
import os
def rename_files():
    #1 get file names from a folder
    file_list = os.listdir(r"F:\Udacity\prank.zip\prank")
    print(file_list)

    #2 for each file, rename filename

rename_files()
```

The following is after the change:

```
    import os
def rename_files():
    #1 get file names from a folder
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\prank")
    print(file_list)

    #2 for each file, rename filename

rename_files()
```

Comment: `prank.zip` isn't a folder.

Comment: Why did you change from your `F` drive to your `C` drive?

Comment: Is `prank.zip` a folder, or is it actually a zip file? If you move the `prank` folder to the top level of your `F:\ ` drive (ie `F:\prank`) do you get the same error?

Comment: Please follow this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296315/renaming-images-in-folder/51296626#51296626

Answer (score -1):

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified

I Got this error rectified by simply changing the "F:\Udacity\prank.zip\prank"
to

"F:/Udacity/prank.zip/prank"

change the backslash \ to front slash /...